# include and header function not working together in single php file

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to include `config.php` file for database after completing  task , redirect to other page  but it shows this error message.

> "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/prasan/public_html/theyplay.in/texttospeech/config.php:16) in
>   /home/prasan/public_html/theyplay.in/texttospeech/input.php on line
>   14"

```
<?php
include("config.php");  
try {

$mi = $_POST['main'];
$i = $_POST['item'];

$dbo->query("INSERT INTO LD (mainitem, subitem, item,fav)VALUES ('$mi','$i',0)") ;

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Edit: `config.php`

```
<?php
$dbhost_name = "localhost";
$database    = "rrr";
$username    = "rrr";
$password    = "rrr";
try {
    $dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbhost_name . ';dbname=' . $database, $username, $password);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: You could not print anything before header redirection.

Comment: config.php produces some output on line 16. Show the code.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: <?Php

$dbhost_name = "localhost";
$database = "rrr";       
$username = "rrr";            
$password = "rrr";           



try {
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost_name.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
?>

Comment: plz tell me config.php file have some problem ..?

Answer (score 0):

Header redirection place inside try. because you have an echo before `header` function

```
<?php
include("config.php");  
try {

    $mi = $_POST['main'];
    $i = $_POST['item'];

    $dbo->query("INSERT INTO LD (mainitem, subitem, item,fav)VALUES ('$mi','$i',0)") ;

    header("Location: index.php");

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Initially I thought the problem was this too but then I realized the output was on line 16 of `config.php`.

Comment: thanx for reply . i try your code but it throw error                    Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/prasan/public_html/theyplay.in/texttospeech/config.php:16) in /home/prasan/public_html/theyplay.in/texttospeech/input.php on line 10

Comment: <?Php

$dbhost_name = "localhost";
$database = "rrr";       
$username = "rrr";            
$password = "rrr";           



try {
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost_name.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
?>

Comment: Avoid print/echo/die("something")/exit("something") etc in config.php (before `header()`)

Comment: remove all print and echo statement from config.php file but it still throw error

Comment: remove also echo from current page before header()

Answer (score 0):

here, php has already sent headers and output buffer to webserver in **config.php** on **line 16**

you should set all headers before any echo or print,

try removing any/all echo statements from config file, otherwise remove `header("Location: index.php");` from you input.php

**EDIT:** one option is there for you, replace by this code

```
<?php
include("config.php");  
try {

$mi = $_POST['main'];
$i = $_POST['item'];

$dbo->query("INSERT INTO LD (mainitem, subitem, item,fav)VALUES ('$mi','$i',0)") ;

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
echo '<script>document.location = "index.php";</script>';
?>
```

Comment: but i want to redirect my page to other location,any other way to redirect to other php page, if it is possible plz tell me actually am new in php so i need help.

Comment: you can use javascript redirect `window.location` or `document.location` one more possible way is using **META** tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://youdestinationurl/'" />`

if you are redirecting then what is the use of `"Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";` as user will not see this